# How to modify iContact signup form so it doesn't redirect to a different page?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to modify the standard iContact sign up form that someone would fill out on a web site to join a mailing list.  By default, the code redirects the user to a success or error page after they attempt to sign up.

What I want to do is not redirect the user and not reload the page: If the user successfully submits the form, the form fields should disappear and a "Thanks for joining!" type of message should appear where the form used to be (without the page reloading).

I'm new at programming but I'm pretty sure that I can accomplish this with jQuery and AJAX.  I've tried messing around with it, but I've never used AJAX before, so I haven't been successful yet.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Here's the code for the form that's on the HTML page (I replaced my account info):

```
<form method="post" action="https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php" name="icpsignup" id="icpsignupZZZZ" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return verifyRequiredZZZZ();" >
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.yoursite.com/newsletter/accepted.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="errorredirect" value="http://www.yoursite.com/newsletter/error.html" />

<div id="SignUp">
<table width="212" class="signupframe" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
  <td width="114" align="right" valign="top">
    <font size="1" face="Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif">*</font> <font size="2">First Name:</font>
  </td>
  <td width="78" align="left">
    <input name="fields_fname" type="text" size="13" maxlength="100" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <font size="1" face="Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif">*</font> <font size="2">E-mail:</font>
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input name="fields_email" type="text" size="13" maxlength="100" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"> <font size="1">*</font><font size="2"> = Required Field</font></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"> <input type="image" name="Submit" value="Submit"  src="../images/join-hdr.jpg" alt="Join our E-mail List" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="listid" value="XXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="specialid:XXXXX" value="ZSMM" />
<input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="YYYYYY" />
<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="ZZZZ" />
<input type="hidden" name="reallistid" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="doubleopt" value="0" />
</div>
</form>
<script src="../Scripts/icontact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's the code for the script that the form references:

```
var icpFormZZZZ = document.getElementById('icpsignupZZZZ');

if (document.location.protocol === "https:")

    icpFormZZZZ.action = "https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php";
function verifyRequired2745() {
  if (icpFormZZZZ["fields_fname"].value == "") {
    icpFormZZZZ["fields_fname"].focus();
    alert("The First Name field is required.");
return false;
  }
  if (icpFormZZZZ["fields_email"].value == "") {
    icpFormZZZZ["fields_email"].focus();
    alert("The E-mail field is required.");
    return false;
  }


return true;
}
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out how to do what I asked above.  However, I did come up with a solution:

Removed the form from the initially visible portion of the page.  I then created a fancyBox that is generated (with an iframe inside of it) when the user clicks a "join our e-mail list" type of graphic.  Then, after the user submits the form that's inside of the fancyBox, they're redirected to a success page, but the page is generated within the fancyBox.  The user can then close the fancyBox and return to the page that they were on. This works good for me, since the user isn't redirected.

Hopefully this helps someone else too!